# Map[Remove[#]] doesn't seem to do anything

Tags: map, variable

If you have a symbol with a value, you can clear it with `Remove[]`. Thus

```
a=1;
Remove[a];
a(*returns unevaluated, as it has no value*)
```

But if you have a list of symbols with values, it does not seem to work to map Remove[] across them. Thus

```
a = 1; b = 2; c = 3;
Map[Remove[#] &, {a, b, c}];
a (* returns 1, as the variable was never cleared *)
```

Is there a good reason why this isn't working?

Comment: Very good reason: after `a = 1`, `a` has the value `1`. So you essentially do `Remove[1]` - change `Remove` to some generic `f` and see how it woks.

Comment: In the second case the list `{a,b,c}` gets evaluated to `{1,2,3}` first, so `Remove` only gets the numbers, as you can see from the errors , "Remove::ssym: 1 is not a symbol. >>"

Comment: I noticed that many people here use `f[#]& /@ ...` instead of `f /@ ...`. I'm not sure why. Not only is it unnecessarily complicated, it also effectively removes any `Hold*` attributes the function may have.

Comment: @Szabolcs [Turns out it's a habit.](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/131514/importing-a-matrix-into-an-equation)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As stated in the comments, `a` is evaluated before being fed into `Remove`. We can prevent this by using `Unevaluated`:

```
a = 1; b = 2; c = 3;
Remove /@ Unevaluated[{a, b, c}];
a
```

> ```
> a
> ```

One can also use `Apply` instead of `Map` to effectively achieve `Remove[a, b, c]`:

```
a = 1; b = 2; c = 3;
Remove @@ Unevaluated[{a, b, c}];
a
```

> ```
> a
> ```

Comment: Or just `Remove[a, b, c]`

Comment: @BobHanlon Yes, good point. I assume OP is in some situation (not sure how) where he can't manually type out the variables.