# Importing a matrix into an equation

Tags: matrix

So here is my function:

```
f[a_, b_ ,c_ ] = -255 + a ((0.91 - 0.91 c) - 0.01 b)
```

and a matrix with my calculated variables:

```
m = {{4,5,3},{3,5,7},{2,9,4}}
```

How can I apply the matrix to the function `f` so that I will have a numeric output like: `{-1.092*10^11, -8.19*10^10, -5.46*10^10}`?

Comment: You mean that `{4,5,3}` is the `a` in `f`?

Comment: No, sorry, like `m={{a,b,c},{a,b,c},{a,b,c}}`

Comment: So, you mean to run through `m` so that, for example, `f[4,5,3]`? But that returns `-262.48`...

Comment: yes, it wouldn't be a problem if I were doing it by hand, but my matrix has 2500 rows...

Comment: I meant that you wrote that you want to get `-1.092*10^11` etc. as output, hence my concern. Nevertheless: `f[##] & @@@ m`.

Comment: Does `f @@@ m` give what you need?

Comment: @kglr I need to finally get rid of the habit of using `##` in such situations :/

Comment: It worked. Thank you. I was missing the `##`.

Comment: Why? is the `##` a problem? 
@kglr - Yes that works as well.

Comment: @Siggi They are basically the same, but `f@@@m` is shorter to type.

Comment: Gotcha. Thanks!

Comment: @corey979, it took me a while to kick that `f[#]&` habit:)